# R-package deSolve: Error in checkFunc

Tags: r, ode, differential-equations

I'm fairly new with R and I'm trying to solve a system of differential equations with de deSolve package.

I have a total of 10000 timesteps and every 100 timesteps i have to change the values of the variables.
The code i tried gives me following error:

```
Error in checkFunc(Func2, times, y, rho) : 
  The number of derivatives returned by func() (2) must equal the length of the initial conditions vector (3)
```

I'm not quite sure where the error comes from. 
Here is my code so far:

```
library(deSolve)

#--------variables and parameter--------------------------


parameters <- c(up = 0.0001, hm = 0.1, hp = 0,889, mm = 0.1 , nt = 100)
yini <- c(u = 1, m = 0.001, h = 0.001)
times <- seq(0,100, by=0.1)
out<- NULL

#--------functions---------------------------------------
DiffU <- function(t, yini, parameters){
  with(as.list(c(yini, parameters)),{

    #functions
    du <- -(up*u) + hm*h + (1/2*nt)*h
    dm <- hp*h - mm*m - (1/nt)*m

    # return functions
    list(c(du, dm))
  })
}

#---------------------------------------------
repeat{
  out<- rbind(out, ode(yini, times, DiffU, parameters))
  yini<-c(u = u+0.5*h, m = 0.001, h = m+0.5*h)
  x<- x+1
  if (x==100){
    break
  }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions to get rid of the error or to improve the code?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you have two derivatives 'du' and 'dm', but three values for yini ('u', 'm' and 'h'). This causes the error.

One solution is (1) add a third derivative or (2) remove 'h' from yini and add it to parameters.